# ffmpeg зависает в avcodec_encode_video2

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Кодирую видео поток с помощью ffmeg. Оболочка QT Creator. OC Windows 7. Язык C++. Компилятор MinGW. Кодек h264.

Есть функция, которой на вход я даю кадр, а мне должна вернуть закодированный массив байт. Внутри этой функции происходит зависание при вызове avcodec_encode_video2, но ни при первом вызове, а при произвольном.
То есть на некотором(рандомном) кодировании кадра виснет(от 100 до 10000го).

```
QByteArray VideoEncoder::createFrameVideoFromImage(QImage picture)
{
    //создаем новый пустой кадр и выделяем под него память...
    AVFrame* frame_source = av_frame_alloc();        
    //Записываем в этот кадр биты рисунка...
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)frame_source, picture.bits(), AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, this->width_frame, this->height_frame);

    //Создаем пустой кадр, в котором будет храниться кадр в YUV
    AVFrame* frame_dst = av_frame_alloc();

    //Выделяем под него нужное количество памяти
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)frame_dst, (uint8_t*)this->inbuffer, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, this->width_frame, this->height_frame);

    //Преобразование кадра в RGB в кадр YUV
    sws_scale(this->convert_rgb_yuv, frame_source->data, frame_source->linesize,
        0, this->ctx_codec_in->height, frame_dst->data, frame_dst->linesize);

    // Создаем пакет, в котором будет записан видеокадр
    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);
    packet.data = NULL;
    packet.size = 0;
    packet.pts = packet.dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

    // Производим кодирование кадра в видеокадр...
    int nOutputSize = 0;
    if (avcodec_encode_video2(this->ctx_codec_in, &packet, frame_dst, &nOutputSize) < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "VideoEncoder error";
    }
    this->traffic += packet.size;

    //Преобразуем полученный видеокадр в массив байт
    QByteArray data_frame = QByteArray((char*)packet.data, packet.size);

    //Очистка памяти
    av_frame_free(&frame_source);
    av_frame_free(&frame_dst);
    av_free_packet(&packet);

    return data_frame;
}
```

Кто чем может помочь? Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: Поясните, как кадр из `picture` попадает во `frame_dst`?

Comment: Сначала `avpicture_fill` кладет `picture` в `frame_source`, затем [sws_scale](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/swscale_8h.html) кладет кадр в `frame_dst` из `frame_sourse`.

Comment: Большое преобразование кадра делаете (маштаб сильно изменется)?  Покажите вызов `sws_getContext()`

Comment: `this->convert_rgb_yuv = sws_getContext(this->ctx_codec_in->width, this->ctx_codec_in->height,
                    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                    this->ctx_codec_in->width, this->ctx_codec_in->height,
                    this->ctx_codec_in->pix_fmt,
                    SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);`